# Which is the recommended powershell executionpolicy in deployed machine?

Tags: security, powershell

I am deploying some powershell script as part of my application.

When the user need to run that script , I just wanted to temporarily change the set-executionpolicy. So i documented as follows.

The user should type the following command before executing the script.

> Set-ExecutionPolicy Allsigned -Scope Process

It will just set as temporarily in the session .

Is this the recommended approach as per security guide?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Powershell.exe`'s parameter `-executionpolicy` to set the policy for a single script execution like so,

```
c:\>powershell -executionpolicy allsigned -file c:\myScript.ps1
```

You could wrap the command in a .cmd script and instruct users to run the batch script. Thus you don't need to worry about the execution policy at all. In contrast, by setting the execution policy for current process, you are likely to alter the user's session settings.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for.  I didn't want to permanently change clients' permissions, and getting the existing permissions was kludgy.